# Globally Existing Integrating Factors for a homogeneous ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Consider the ODE $$f(x,y)dx+g(x,y)dy=0$$
where $f(x,y),g(x,y)$ are homogeneous polynomials of $x,y$ with the same degree in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I've encountered a problem which asks me to construct a smooth function $h(x,y)$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $fhdx+ghdy=dF$ for some function $F\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and of course $h\not\equiv0$ (meaning that for some $x_0,y_0\in\mathbb{R}$, $h(x_0,y_0)\not=0$).

I know that we can take $h(x,y)=\frac{1}{xf(x,y)+yg(x,y)}$ and checking is simple. However, this may fail to exist at zeros of $xf+yg$. So I wonder whether there is an integrating factor (i.e. some $h$ with the desired property) which exists on the whole plane.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is NO.

Consider $f(x,y)=-g(x,y)=x+y$. We assume the contrast that $h(x,y)\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ and $F(x,y)\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ satisfy $dF=fhdx+ghdy$. Then $dF=(x+y)h(x,y)d(x-y)$.

Consider the transformation $s=x+y,t=x-y$ and the function $\tilde{h}(s,t)=h(x,y)$. Then the 1-form $dF=s\tilde{h}(s,t)dt$. From $d(dF)=0$ we see that $\frac{\partial}{\partial s}(s\tilde{h}(s,t))=0$. Hence $\tilde{h}+s\partial_s\tilde{h}=0$.

However, for each fixed $t$, this equation is a simple ODE, its solution satisfies $\tilde{h}(s,t)=\frac{sgn(s)}{s}\tilde{h}(sgn(s),t)$ when $s\not=0$. Here $sgn(s)=\frac{s}{|s|}$ for $s\not=0$. Moreover we have $\tilde{h}(0,t)=0$. Since $\tilde{h}(s,t)$ is smooth, we get $h(1,t)=h(-1,t)=0$. This indeed tells us $h\equiv 0$.